# How do I instantiate a specific subclass based on arguments passed to __init__?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm wrapping a remote XML-based API from python 2.7.  The API throws errors by sending along a `<statusCode>` element as well as a `<statusDescription>` element.  Right now, I catch this condition and raise a single exception type.  Something like:

```
class ApiError(Exception):
    pass

def process_response(response):
    if not response.success:
        raise ApiError(response.statusDescription)
```

This works fine, except I now want to handle errors in a more sophisticated fashion.  Since I have the `statusCode` element, I would like to raise a specific subclass of ApiError based on the statusCode.  Effectively, I want my wrapper to be extended like this:

```
class ApiError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, description, code):
        # How do I change self to be a different type?
        if code == 123:
            return NotFoundError(description, code)
        elif code == 456:
            return NotWorkingError(description, code)

class NotFoundError(ApiError):
    pass

class NotWorkingError(ApiError):
    pass

def process_response(response):
    if not response.success:
        raise ApiError(response.statusDescription, response.statusCode)

def uses_the_api():
    try:
        response = call_remote_api()
    except NotFoundError, e:
        handle_not_found(e)
    except NotWorkingError, e:
        handle_not_working(e)
```

The machinery for tying specific `statusCode`'s to specific subclasses is straightforward.  But what I want is for that to be buried inside of ApiError somewhere.  Specifically, I don't want to change process_response except to pass in the value `statusCode`.

I've looked at metaclasses, but not sure they help the situation, since `__new__` gets write-time arguments, not run-time arguments.  Similarly unhelpful is hacking around `__init__` since it isn't intended to return an instance.  So, how do I instantiate a specific subclass based on arguments passed to `__init__`?

Comment: Why do you want to use a class if you need a method? Use a function that returns a different instance based on the status code

Comment: @GabiPurcaru Good question.  Because I don't want to significantly change the `raise ApiError()` line in `process_response`.  I'm interested in how this could be done without disturbing existing `raise` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that will yield requested error class basing on description.
Something like this:

```
def get_valid_exception(description, code):
    if code == 123:
        return NotFoundError(description, code)
    elif code == 456:
        return NotWorkingError(description, code)
```

Depending on your requirements and future changes, you could create exceptions with different arguments or do anything else, without affecting code that uses this function.

Then in your code you can use it like this:

```
def process_response(response):
    if not response.success:
        raise get_valid_exception(response.statusDescription, response.statusCode)
```

Comment: Thanks.  In lieu of a more elegant solution, this is more or less what I've ended up implementing.  It's deliberate and concise, even if `raise get_valid_exception()` is less than perfect.

Answer (score 3):

A factory function is going to be much easier to understand. Use a dictionary to map codes to exception classes:

```
exceptions = {
    123: NotFoundError,
    456: NotWorkingError,
    # ...
}

def exceptionFactory(description, code):
    return exceptions[code](description, code)
```

Comment: I like your code example better, but this answer is functionally equivalent to @Abgan's, and his came first, so I accepted his answer instead.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a series of subclasses and use the base class' `__new__` as a factory for the children.  However, that's probably overkill here; you could just create a simple factory method or class.  If you wanted to get fancy in another direction though, you could create a metaclass for the base class that would automatically add your subclasses to a factory when they are created.  Something like:

```
class ApiErrorRegistry(type):

    code_map = {}

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        try:
            mapped_code = attrs.pop('__code__')
        except KeyError:
            if name != 'ApiError':
                raise TypeError('ApiError subclasses must define a __code__.')
            mapped_code = None
        new_class = super(ApiErrorRegistry, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        if mapped_code is not None:
            ApiErrorRegistry.code_map[mapped_code] = new_class
        return new_class

def build_api_error(description, code):

    try:
        return ApiErrorRegistry.code_map[code](description, code)
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError('No error for code %s registered.' % code)


class ApiError(Exception):

    __metaclass__ = ApiErrorRegistry


class NotFoundError(ApiError):

    __code__ = 123


class NotWorkingError(ApiError):

    __code__ = 456


def process_response(response):

    if not response.success:
        raise build_api_error(response.statusDescription, response.statusCode)

def uses_the_api():
    try:
        response = call_remote_api()
    except ApiError as e:
        handle_error(e)
```

Comment: Your example here is more or less the solution I was prepping to build.  Looking at it laid out like that, however, `raise ApiErrorRegistry.build_error(description, code)` smells worse than just a simple `raise build_error(description, code)`.  So I think I'll probably settle on a factory function if something better doesn't come along.

Comment: Also, putting a `handle()` method on the exception subclasses seems suspicious.  It doesn't apply to the wrapper I'm currently writing, and I have trouble envisioning a case where I would want the exception-handling logic in the class itself instead of in functions such as `uses_the_api()`.

Comment: I was just trying to make it more concise, and it seemed like it made logical sense to attach the builder to the registry.  Of course, there's no requirement to do so.  As to `handle`, I didn't know how general use you intended this to be.  If it doesn't make sense there, again, just separate the handler out.

Comment: Putting the builder in the registry does make some logical sense, but I don't like the way it looks on the raise line.  If I'm going to give up aesthetics in the calling code for the sake of this implementation, I'd probably prefer the simplicity of a separate factory function like @Abgan's and Martijn Pieters' answers.

Comment: Then make a separate factory that just references the registry class' value.  I made it a classmethod in part so that it would be appropriate for the private-ish `_code_map` to be accessed from the factory method, but if you just access the registry from a factory function external to the registry class, it will still work.  This is a style thing, not a functional question at this point.

Comment: It's nitpicking on style, I know.  But style is an important factor in API design, which is why I'm asking this question.  I appreciate how your answer shows one of the class-based factory solutions, but it also entails a lot of complexity, and doesn't appear to yield a significantly better API than the factory function answers.

Comment: Now it's a simple builder function, and handle was moved out of the errors.  Alternatively, the module could have provided a wrapper to access the class method.  I understand the desire to keep an API clean and functional, but for illustrating a logical paradigm, it seemed less important to me.